# Convolution to do it in block by block of a whole matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

i have a kernel, which performs convolution on 18x32 (Matrix size ) with 3x3 (Filter size) to produce output matrix of size 16x32.
i need to know how could i use this kernel to perform convolution on 66x66(zero padded on all the side so original matrix is 64x64) matrix  to get 64x64 matrix as the output.
I'm interested in the logic or the algorithm to do this operation.

Comment: once you convolute on cells outside input matrix you use either background value (like 0) or the closest edge value of matrix. Which depends on what you want to achieve ...

Comment: will try that, thanks